# Python socket ssl certified problems

Tags: sockets, openssl, python-3.6

I'm trying to build a very simpleton server / client ssl socket that makes something similar 'Github' does when you register a public key to authenticate users on server. Since I have no clue how to start to build it, I decided to start from the beggining reading the Python's basics about ssl socket [here] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html), and I ' d produced this until now:

Server code:

```
import socket
import ssl

from time import sleep

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('certs/ca.pem', 'certs/ca.key')

while(True):
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
            sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8443))
            sock.listen(5)
            with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
                conn, addr = ssock.accept()
                with conn:
                    print('Connected by', addr)
                    while True:
                        data = conn.recv(1024)
                        if not data:
                            break
                        conn.sendall(data)
                        sleep(.5)
    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        print("Jeeez! " + str(e))
        pass
sleep(.5)
```

Client code

```
import socket
import ssl


context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations('certs/client.csr')
hostname='127.0.0.1'
port=8443
with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        ssock.sendall(b'Hello, world')
        data = ssock.recv(1024)

    print('Received', repr(data))
```

The server starts without problem, but the client throws the following error when I run it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "client.py", line 7, in
>
> context.load_verify_locations('certs/client.csr') ssl.SSLError: [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)

My guess is I'm building certifiers wrong, but sincerly I'm lost here. Can you give a little hand here, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have a valid certificate? Does client.csr contain a list of trusted certificates? Usually a file ending with .csr contains a PKCS10 certificate signing request, which is not what belongs here.

Comment: I don't  know! I've created certifiers for the server and a client components. I understand your question, but I can't transpose this in the solution. It's exactly this part I'm trying to figure out! What should I do? Concatenate the client certifier into server certifier? I don't know!